# Possible to make SMIME signatures not appear as an attachment? (e.g. in Gmail)

Tags: gmail, smime

We are using SMIME across our organisation and are getting complaints that the SMIME signature is appearing as an attachment in various email clients. (gmail)

Is there any way to edit the SMTP envelope or data so that it doesn't look like an attachment (like PGP?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email client, whatever it is, has to have a special plugin to be able to understand SMIME and read messages that are signed or encrypted with SMIME.  Gmail does not, by default, come with this plugin.

Here is an example of a Firefox plugin that adds SMIME support in Gmail:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gmail-smime/

Or

https://www.penango.com/products/penango-for-webmail